# SharePoint 2016 Subsite renders code instead of actual content

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-server, sub-site, public-website

I am running an On Premises instance of SharePoint 2016. I am trying to create a subsite with a blog layout and followed the general instructions to do so.

However after the process was completed, the browser navigated to http://servername/blog/default.aspx, but is merely and only showing me the default.aspx code, as opposed to rendering the information that should be displayed.

Below is a screenshot: 
[image]

At this point, I can't help but feel like I am missing something...as straight forward as the process seems.

Any insight into this issue?

Comment: Exceptionally odd. I've never seen it do that before. Have you tried any other type of sub-site to see how it acts?

Comment: jpollar, it seemed to be the cahce or something. I ran an iisreset after several hours of trying to figure it out..and ithat worked. Subsequent subsites showed no similar behaviours though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemed to be the cahce or something. I ran an iisreset after several hours of trying to figure it out..and that worked. Subsequent sub sites showed no similar behaviours though.

Rather interesting.

Comment: Very odd. I've never seen SharePoint do that before.

Comment: Please mark this as the answer.